# Silverstripe ORM: sort by number of $belongs_many_many relation

Tags: silverstripe

How do I get the most active blog tags in a query?

I have this two DataObjects:

```
class BlogTag extends DataObject {

//...

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'BlogPosts' => 'BlogPost',
    );
```

and

```
class BlogPost extends Page {

//...

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Tags' => 'BlogTag',
    );
```

Now i wonder how I can get a DataList with all BlogTags ordered by how many blog posts they're related to. This is what i have already, but somehow i don't get how to sort by BlogPosts.Count():

```
public function getPopularBlogTags($limit = 5) {
    $tags = BlogTag::get()
        ->sort('BlogPosts.Count()') //doesn't work
        ->limit($limit);

    return $tags;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution with help on IRC (thanks barry and mark)

```
public function getPopularBlogTags($limit = 5) {
    $tags = BlogTag::get()
        ->setQueriedColumns(['ID', 'Title', 'Count(*)'])
        ->leftJoin('BlogPost_Tags','bpt.BlogTagID = BlogTag.ID','bpt')
        ->sort('Count(*) DESC')
        ->alterDataQuery(function($query){
            $query->groupBy('BlogTag.ID');
        })
        ->limit($limit);

    return $tags;
}
```

And in the template:

```
   <% loop $PopularBlogTags %>
        <a href="$Link" title="$Title">$Title ($BlogPosts.Count())</a>
        <% if not $Last %> | <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
```

Comment: This was helpful to me, thanks guys! Note that it seems to me you can remove the `->setQueriedColumns()` part as including `COUNT(*)` in your sort clause will cause that column to be added automatically.

Comment: I think `->setQueriedColumns()` tells the DB also just to return the data we need for the current action, so it doesn't return _all_ data... It should be faster then..?

Comment: You would think so, but it doesn't seem to work that way for me. If I look at `$tags->sql()` the result is exactly the same with or without the `->setQueriedColumns(['ID', 'Title', 'Count(*)'])` part. I'm not sure if the name of that method is misleading and it actually just *adds* queried columns, or if it is being overridden. In any case I think that trying to limit the queried columns wouldn't be the best option in general cases, as it would mean you wouldn't have access to the full objects in your templates, and creates a tighter coupling / less flexibility.

Comment: Of course, it depends on each use case and I also prefer to get the whole DataObject back.